# Two symmetrical coins - the difference of the tails - comparison of probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

We have two pairs of summetric coins.

First pair: $A1$ and $B1$.

Second pair: $A2$ and $B2$.

The probability of drawing a tails for $A1$ and $B1$ coins is $\frac{1}{2}$ (perfectly symmetrical coins).

The probability that the tails are drawn for coins $A2$ and $B2$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ ($n>2$) (coins are not symmetrical - they cheat - they favor eagles).

We throw a pair of coins $n$ times (per coin).

$P1$ = the probability that the difference between the number of tails on coin $A1$ and the tails on coin $B1$ will be at least $k$ ($n > k > 1$).

$P2$ = the probability that the difference between the number of tails on coin $A2$ and the tails on coin $B2$ will be at least $k$ ($n > k > 1$).

Is $P1 > P2$?

Can someone prove it?

Coin throws are independent.